# Using `post_url` with a variable argument

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've got some related posts in my Jekyll site, and I want to link them to each other. I'd like to just name the related posts in the yaml front matter, then when I render a post, include some nav bar that adds in links to the other posts.

For example:

```
title: This is Post One
layout: post
followup_post: 2013-02-02-two
---
Blah blah blah one.
```

Then in my post layout:

```
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
{% if page.followup_post.size > 0 %}
    <a href="{% post_url page.followup_post %}">follow up</a>
{% endif %}
{{ content }}
```

However, this doesn't work, because `post_url` thinks I'm giving it a literal string when I want to give it a variable name.

Is there a way in Jekyll, without using a (GitHub-forbidden) plugin, to get a post URL for a post if the post's name in a variable?

Comment: What kind if permalink do you use?

Comment: I'm using `/:categories/:title/`, but I think it doesn't matter -- Jekyll errors out when I try to give `post_url` the variable name as an argument.

Comment: You can try to capture it in a variable and then throw it to post_url, i.e. `{% capture followup_url %} {{ page.followup_post }} {% endcapture %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is two things you could do:

1.) Loop over the site.posts array until you find the matching post object and use that
or 
2.) Create the post url yourself, if you have a simple enough permalink (for example, i'm using simply `:title`)

Comment: Ahh okay I'll try just looping through posts until I get something that matches.  Great idea!  It should have occurred to me already; I've solved most of my Jekyll challenges by looping through every post way more times than you'd think was healthy :)